# How To Arrange Table Data in Parent_Id And Child_Id Wise Via Sql-Server Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

How To Arrange Table Data in Parent_Id And Child_Id Wise Via Sql-Server Query?

**My Query**

```
 select CLevel_Id,Category_Name,Parent_Id,Child_Id,Level_Id from Category_Level
 order by Parent_Id asc
```

**Current Output**

```
CLevel_Id   Category_Name   Parent_Id   Child_Id    Level_Id
12             Jewelry           1           0             1
14             Rings             2           1             2
15             Men-Rings         3           2             3
17             Women-Rings       4           2             3
18             Earrings          5           1             2
20             Women-Earings     6           5             3
1013           Metal-Fashion     7           3             4
1015           Diamond-Fashion   8           4             4
1016           Semi-Set          9           6             4
```

**Expected Output**

```
CLevel_Id   Category_Name   Parent_Id   Child_Id    Level_Id
12             Jewelry           1           0             1
14             Rings             2           1             2
15             Men-Rings         3           2             3
1013           Metal-Fashion     7           3             4
17             Women-Rings       4           2             3
1015           Diamond-Fashion   8           4             4
18             Earrings          5           1             2
20             Women-Earings     6           5             3
1016           Semi-Set          9           6             4
```

please help me

Comment: the result doesn't coincide with your query

Comment: What is the root node here?  I would expect to see some record having a parent as being `NULL`, but I don't see this.  The answer you want is probably just a recursive hierarchical query.

Comment: you want solution for both SQL Server & MySQL ?

Comment: @Squirrel only SQL Server

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Root node is Jewelry Child_Id=0

Comment: which column is sorted here?..or...which column you want to sort? I seen, there is no columns are in sorted.

Comment: Your definition of `Parent_Id` and `Child_Id` is unconventional and rather confusing. `"Root node is Jewelry Child_Id=0"`

Comment: @Squirrel i want to my data arrange looks like in Tree Format

Comment: So with "parent_id" you actually mean "id", and with "child_id" you actually mean "parent_id". Neat. Also, you need a preorder traversal.

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis Yes, but how can make query i dont know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use a Recursive CTE.

Assuming you have max 9 per level. Using single digit as the seq level. If you have more than 9, you will need to use 2 digits like 01, 02 etc

```
; with
rcte as
(
    -- Anchor member, seq = 1
    select  *, seq = convert(varchar(100), '1')
    from    Category_Level
    where   Child_Id    = 0

    union all

    -- recursive member, concatenate to the seq
    select  c.*, seq = convert(varchar(100), 
                    r.seq 
                +   convert(varchar(10), row_number() over (partition by r.seq 
                                                                order by c.Child_Id)))
    from    Category_Level c
        inner join rcte r   on  c.Child_Id  = r.Parent_Id
)
select  *
from    rcte 
order by seq

/* RESULT
CLevel_Id   Category_Name        Parent_Id   Child_Id    Level_Id    seq
----------- -------------------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -------
12          Jewelry              1           0           1           1
14          Rings                2           1           2           11
15          Men-Rings            3           2           3           111
1013        Metal-Fashion        7           3           4           1111
17          Women-Rings          4           2           3           112
1015        Diamond-Fashion      8           4           4           1121
18          Earrings             5           1           2           12
20          Women-Earings        6           5           3           121
1016        Semi-Set             9           6           4           1211

(9 rows affected)
*/
```

Comment: So each time you take the seq of the parent and append the child's order? Excellent!

Comment: yes. so you get a long string of seq concatenate together